# Jquery Date Picker culture issue

Tags: jquery-ui

I am using jquery.ui.datepicker in asp.net mvc3 on windows 7.I changed my system date format as

- **mm/dd/yyyy**

  to
- **yyyy-mm-dd**

  Then my project calender format also changed and default dates coming.Some times date picker calender is not showing.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this issue

Answer (score 6):

Sangar82's answer is the most complete and correct (I upvoted it for that reason) but a quicker way of just setting the format without creating/downloading a localisation file is:

```
$(".dateinput").datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'});
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to use Datepicker Localization

> The date picker is designed to allow localizations to be easily created and used. Many localizations are already available, and additional ones are welcomed.
>
> The date picker plugin maintains a manager object, $.datepicker, that lets you register new localizations. This object maintains an array of localization settings indexed by language, with '' accessing the default (English) version: $.datepicker.regional['fr'].
>
> A new localization should be created in a separate JavaScript file named ui.datepicker-.js. Within a document.ready event it should add a new entry into the $.datepicker.regional array, indexed by the language code.
>
> http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/Localization

Code:

```
$('selector').datepicker($.datepicker.regional['<language>']);
```

Example

```
$('.myinput').datepicker($.datepicker.regional['fr']);
```

When you download the Jquery UI  you can find in the following folder the translation of datepicker on several languages (69 translations)

```
 development-bundle/ui/bundle/i18n
```

Example of use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui/development-bundle/ui/bundle/i18n/ui.datepicker-fr.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['fr']);
        $("#StartDate").datepicker();
    }); 
 </script>
```